# Extract layouts of an Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I have to develop an Android app with some UI components similar to another app (Which I do not own). To speed up the development I thought of starting my app taking the other app layout as a base, and then make changes to that.

As far as I know, if I have a rooted phone, it would be possible to extract the `res` folder and look at how the layout for that app is designed, isn't it?

Would this be the best way? Or there is some other method that allows me to create my layout based on other app?

**NOTE**: I do not want to clone the app, I only want some functionality their UI offers, and see how they have develop some UI components.

**EDIT**: I solve the problem using `apktool`, as **joebro** suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at Apktool. It is a tool to decompile APKs that will allow you to have a look at the res folder of an APK

https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it up.

Comment: But that requieres me to have the apk of the ohter app. Currently I only have the app installed via Play Store. So I would need a rooted phone, right?

Comment: No. There are plenty of sites that will allow you to download the APK file from the play store. Here is one for example: https://apkpure.com. So you will download the APK, decompile it with Apktool, and then you'll have that APK's res folder.